# How to use xstream fro xml serialization in eclipse

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, xstream

I am having some trouble figuring out how to download and use xstream in eclipse.  When I download the binary distribution from the website, I get a zip file.  Where should I extract it, and how do I use it?

Edit:

OK, I have added it to my build path, but now when I try to use XStream to serialize an `ArrayList<Earmark>` where `Earmark` is a class that I have defined, I get the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParserException
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:334)
at examples.TestEarmarkExtractor.SerializeEarmarks(TestEarmarkExtractor.java:19)
at examples.TestEarmarkExtractor.main(TestEarmarkExtractor.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 3 more
```

Update: The error is occurring *before* I try the serialization.  It occurs on the line

```
XStream xs = new XStream();
```

Comment: Maybe that download was corrupted somehow? Try again, or try from a different browser, extract the zip contents and add it to your project classpath.

Comment: Note that this is more of a general "How do I use a library in Eclipse" question rather than a specific XStream question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Extract the zip file to a directory (e.g. `C:\Program Files\XStream`)
2. In eclipse, right-click on your project and select `Build Path > Configure Build Path...`
3. Select `Libraries` tab
4. Select `Add External Jars..`
5. Navigate to the `lib` folder of your XStream download and select the jar(s) to be added
6. Select `Open`
7. Select `OK`

And here's the [Two Minute Tutorial](http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html) on how to use XStream.

Comment: Ok, I did this, and now I get a bunch of exceptions when I try to run it.  I have added the exceptions to my question.

Comment: @Daniel, Did you import the necessary classes?

Comment: Hi @Daniel  still i m getting same set of Exception ? any clue how to solve it...

Comment: @KarthikeyanArumugam, Are you not using eclipse?

Comment: @Daniel If you found out the solution you should have explained it here... that was really selfish of you to just walk off!

Comment: @Marci-man if you still are looking for a solution, which you most likely aren't, you follow the same process described in this answer, but after you have imported the xstream-x.x.x.jar file as an external jar, you must navigate to lib/xstream and import all those jars as external jars. So all together you should have a long list of all referenced jars.

Comment: @grimrader22 I've done all that, and I'm still stuck with "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/thoughtworks/xstream/XStream" on the same line as the original asker, which is       
"XStream xstream = new XStream();"

Answer (score 3):

Got this exception, then I download kxml2-min-2.3.0.jar and add it as a library and now it works (using xstream 1.4.4.jar)

Answer (score 2):

You need to unzip the .zip file to get at the .jar file, which you put on your classpath for your project in eclipse (Google if you don't know how to add third party library .jars to your project classpath in Eclipse).

Once it is added to your project's classpath, you use the classes contained within it as you would any other classes, and the documentation on the XStream website tells you how to use them.

Good choice by the way, XStream is great!

Answer (score 2):

You can add this library:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xmlpull</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlpull</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had added the two libraries: `dom4j-2.0.0-ALPHA-2.jar` and `xstream-1.4.7.jar` and the same issue were displayed. After adding the `kxml2-min-2.3.0.jar` the issue is not happening.